# Overriding Gradle Settings with Defaults

Tags: java, maven, ant, gradle

I'm working on a codebase with many ANT style projects with a root project and many sub projects.

In the root project build.gradle file we declare the following settings to allow Gradle to use the ANT Structure:

```
subprojects {    
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = files('src')
            resources.srcDirs = files('config')
        }
        test {
            java.srcDirs = files('test/unit')
            resources.srcDirs = files('test/unit')
        }
    }
}
```

I want to convert the sub projects over to the Maven structure one by one, the only way I can think to do this is to stick the following in each subprojects build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = files('src/main/java')
        resources.srcDirs = files('src/main/resources')
    }
    test {
        java.srcDirs = files('src/test/java')
        resources.srcDirs = files('src/main/resources')
    }
}
```

Which seems a bit overkill. Is there an easier way to default the sourceSets back to the default Maven style in an individual subproject without the above?

Comment: Why not specify the sourceSets in all subprojects then convert them one by one, removing it when done?

Comment: @fge That was the original plan, it'd be easier to have some sort of exclusion list in the root project if possible though, means when we're done we don't have to modify every project build file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other option would be to exclude the migrated projects from that configuration.

```
configure(subprojects - project(':mavenProject')) {
    // configure ant source sets
}
```